# Internal Server Error - getDateFormatter() on null

Tags: updates, updating, auto-updates, manual-updates

When doing a manual update from 2.6.3012 to 2.7.8, I get the following error:

> **Internal Server Error**
>   Call to a member function getDateFormatter() on null

I get the following error when enabling devMode:

[image: impossible to invoque getOrientation on null variable.]

Updating from the Dashboard fails too, but in a slightly more verbose fashion:

> [curl] 28: Operation timed out after 30001 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received [url] https://download.craftcdn.com/craft/2.7/2.7.8/Patch/2.6.3012/**[redacted string of numbers]**.zip

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Craft support had suggested looking into the `locales` table, which had a singular entry for `en_us`.

What allowed me to update was to copy the following folder and its content: `app/framework/i18n/data`. It was entirely missing from the Craft-2.7.8.zip file I had downloaded.